# How to get the nested attribute's user_id for notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

How can I send a notification with the dueler's name who created the duel?

[image]

Right now both `dueler's` get a notification, but with their own name listed in the notification as `notification.dueler.user.name`

**model**

```
class Dueler < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :duel
  after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications

private
  def create_notification
    notifications.create(
      duel:    duel,
      user:    user, # I'm not sure if or how to rewrite this line so that the notification shows the user's name  who created the duel.      
      read:    false
    )
  end
end
```

**notification**

```
<%= link_to notification.dueler.user.name, user_path(notification.dueler.user_id) %> challenged you to a <%= link_to "duel", notification_duel_request_path(notification, notification.duel_id) %>
```

**rails c**

```
Notification.find(223)
 id: 223,
 user_id: 2, # This is who created the duel
 duel_id: 112,
 dueler_id: 181>
Notification.last
 id: 224,
 user_id: 114,
 duel_id: 112,
 dueler_id: 182>
Duel.last
 id: 112,
Dueler.find(181)
 id: 181,
 user_id: 2,
 challenge_id: 302,
 duel_id: 112,
Dueler.last
 id: 182,
 user_id: 114,
 challenge_id: 410,
 duel_id: 112,
```

Comment: update question with `notification` model. @AnthonyGalli.com

Comment: I do not really understand the question. What's the desired behaviour/output?

Comment: You should be using an association callback on the `Duel` class instead. `has_many :duelers, after_add: :create_notifications`. However as @AndreyDeineko has allready said its pretty unclear what you actually want. Do you want to send a message to all the participants in a duel that someone has joined? Or just to send a message to the user that is joining?

Comment: I'm guessing your `Notification` class knows far too much about `Duel` and `Dueller` as well. Your `Duel` class should be creating the message for the notification. You only really need to have a recipient association on a  Notification system. Rethink. Decouple. KISS.

Comment: In the notification model there is just `belongs_to :duel belongs_to :dueler belongs_to :user` @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I added a pic to hopefully clarify question.

Comment: `notification.user.name`?

Comment: @max the notification is sending (as shown by image) so I don't think it should be in the `duel` model. For every duel that's created two duelers are created with it. One dueler will be `current_user` and the other will be the challenged user. The challenged user should receive a notification saying "_____ challenged you to a duel", but right now it says "You challenged you to a duel, which doesn't make sense. Cheers! :)

Comment: That gives error @AndreyDeineko: `undefined local variable or method 'notification' for #<Dueler:0x007feb7d91b980>`

Comment: same deal with @AndreyDeineko `user:    notification.duel.users.where.not(id: current_user.id).first.name`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com thats exactly why it should not be in the Dueler model in the first place. You can do it but you would have to look at `duel.duellers` and its just really dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your Dueler class really be responsible for notifying the other participants? - I don't think so. In this case its just a m2m join model.

Also your model is not aware of the session - so it does not know which of the two duelers actually created a duel. While you could look at `duel.user` you just might be creating a chicken vs egg scenario.

Instead you might want to choose a more sane and decoupled solution rather than moshing all your models into a dense soup.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :duelers
  has_many :duels, through: :duelers
  has_many :notifications
end

class Duel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :duelers
  has_many :users, through: :duelers
end

class Dueler < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:defendant, :challenger]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :duel
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:unread, :read, :trashed]
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here your Notification class should not have to know about `Dueler`, `Duel` or any of the game logic. It just takes a recipient and a message and does its job.

Lets say you have a discrete form on the `users#show` page to create a duel:

```
<%= button_to( "Challenge to a duel", user_duels_path(user_id: @user.to_param), method: :post) %>
```

Which goes to the following action:

```
class Users::DuelsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user

  # POST users/:user_id/duels
  def create
    @duel = Duel.new do |d|
      d.duelers.new(user: current_user, role: :challenger)
      d.duelers.new(user: @user, role: :defendant)
    end

    if @duel.save
      DuelNotifier.new(current_user, @user).send
      redirect_to @duel
    else
      redirect_to @user, alert: 'Duel could not be created'
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

When creating something like in app notifications you don't want to do it  on the model layer:

- models are not session aware.
- callbacks are complex and it is hard to regulate when they are fired.
- its damn hard to test.
- models are not suited to deal with localization issues.
- model callbacks cannot be delegated to jobs
- models cannot broadcast to ActionCable since they are not session aware.

Instead take a few cues from how mailers work:

```
# app/notifiers/duel_notifier.rb
class DuelNotifier 
  attr_accessor :challenger, :defendant

  def initialize(challenger, defendant)
    @challenger, @defendant = challenger, defendant
  end

  def send
    [].tap do |a|
      a.push( @challenger.notifications.create!(
        message: "You have challenged to #{defendant.name} to a duel."
      ) )
      a.push( @defendant.notifications.create!(
        message: "#{challenger.name} has challenged you to a duel."
      ) )
    end
  end
end
```

This is just a simple class that does one job. We can test this in a simple and straight forward manner:

```
RSpec.describe DuelNotifier do
  let(:challenger) { create(:user) }
  let(:defendant) { create(:user) }
  let(:notifier) { described_class.new(challenger, defendant) } 

  it "creates two notifications" do
    expect { notifier.send }.to change(Notification, :count).by(+2)
  end

  it "creates the correct notification for the challenger" do
     notifier.send
     expect(challenger.notifications.last.message).to eq(
       "You have challenged to #{defendant.name} to a duel."
     )
  end

  it "creates the correct notification for the defendant" do
     notifier.send
     expect(defendant.notifications.last.message).to eq(
       "#{challenger.name} has challenged you to a duel."
     )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful answer :) I was playing with it and it was hard for me to implement with my overall project, but I'll definitely come back to this question multiple times in the future when I decide to transition my notifications system to this cleaner system.